# Why doesn't my Terminal show 'last login' message?

Tags: macos, terminal

Terminal.app on my mac used to show `Last login: <date time> on ttys000` as the first line.
However, when I opened it this week, I noticed that it didn't show the message.
Is this normal, or did I do something wrong?

I tried rebooting mac, and tried 'repair disk permissions' in Disk Utility, but neither of them fixed the problem.
I found that `~/.hushlogin` suppresses the message, but no such file was found when I tried `ls -la ~`.

I'm using OS X 10.8.5.

**Edit:**
I installed GPG Suite last weekend.
Does it have something to do with the problem?

**Update:**
I think this problem is systemwide, because it is reproduced in Guest account.
I suspect that the log file of last login may be corrupt.
Is this possible?
How can I check this?

**Update 2:**
I tried opening another window while running `sudo opensnoop -ve -n login`.
I found that `login` failed in opening some files in `/var/log/asl/` and the 'errno values' were '24'.

**Update 3:**
I found that errno 24 meant 'too many open files', and tried reducing the log files by `sudo aslmanager`. This fixed the problem! I don't know why these log files had remained undeleted though.

Comment: And trashing the Terminal preference file?

Comment: ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist

Comment: @AndrewU. I tried trashing the file, but it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Are you sure `ls -l ~/.hushlogin` shows nothing?

Comment: @lhf `ls -la ~/.hushlogin` returned `No such file or directory`.

Answer (score 1):

`login` should display that message unless it is run with a '-q' option or the file '.hushlogin' exists.

It would be good to know the command line for login.

At the command prompt go `ps ax | grep login` and you should get a line for each open Terminal window that reads something like this :

```
login -pf <username>
```

or

```
login -pfl <username> exec -la bash /bin/bash
```

Check that out and see what it says.

`bash` and it's profiles have nothing to do with displaying that message. The setting of the "Shell" preference also makes no difference as `login` is run regardless of how this is set.

If login is  not being run with a -q option then something else is happening. If you try `type -a login` you should get nothing but `login is /usr/bin/login`. I'd also triple check that `~/.hushlogin` does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

### Check settings, ~/.bashrc and ~/.bash_profile

You may have inadvertently changed the following setting in your preferences, which can be accessed either from the menu:

**Terminal>Preferences...**

or by pressing the <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> keys.

The setting you are looking for is in the "shell" tab.  If the run command button is ticked under Startup, that may be your issue.

[image]

If that is not it I would the check the contents of the following files:

~/.bashrc; and

~/bash_profile

Comment: something has definitely changed on your system, I have GPG suite installed as well - that should make no difference. I would check ~/.bash_aliases.  Also would try starting terminal from a newly created user and see if you get the old behaviour back?